# Setting binary value (byte array) to an SOAP element when callling a service

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl, soap-client

I am calling a soap service using java, i do not have any problems with text nodes, but one parameters expects a file content in byte array format. (Not a string form of the file in base64 encoded)

How can I set a binary content (byte array) to a soap message?

```
QName q1 = new Qname(qnameNS, "expectstextvalue", prefix);
SOAPElement e1 = bodyElement.addChildElement(q1);
e1.addTextNode("simple text value");

QName q2 = new Qname(qnameNS, "expectsbytevalue", prefix);
SOAPElement e2 = bodyElement.addChildElement(q2);

//how can i set byte values to a soap message?
//e1.setByte()
```

The wsdl for these parameters are the following:

```
<xs:element name="expectstextvalue" type="xs:string" nillable="true" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="expectsbytevalue" type="xs:base64Binary" nillable="true" minOccurs="0"/>
```

Comment: can we bind a soap message attachment to an soap element, so the receiver bind the attachment to the corresponding node? https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19575-01/819-3669/bnbhf/index.html

Answer (score -1):

If you create `XML`, you can set Your values using `Base64`

Example:

```
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;

final byte[] somethings = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary("Something object in example is string");
```